# getOptionChain in quantmod connection error

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to download options using `getOptionChain()` in the quantmod library.
Here is the complete program

```
#test of quantmod getOptionChain  
rm(list=ls())  
library(quantmod)  
library(jsonlite)  
nflx = getOptionChain('NFLX')
```

Here is the output

> Error in close.connection(URL) : invalid connection

What am I missing?

Comment: This is a known issue. For an alternative solution see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386903/getoptionchain-not-returning-any-data-in-r/38872652#38872652) or [this post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/downloading-option-chain-data-from-google-finance-in-r-an-update/) .

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/92). Use the [development version of quantmod](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod), which should be on CRAN shortly. There's no need to use another package or roll your own solution.